# Redshift SQL: How to only aggregate subsequent rows with a certain value using window functions?

Tags: function, window, amazon-redshift

I have the following table:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 12 |
| 2 | 0 | 13 |
| 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 0 | 22 |
| 7 | 0 | 20 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 | 10 |
| 10 | 0 | 11 |
| 11 | 0 | 12 |

I would like to transform the data in a way that subsequent rows (after ordering by A ascending), are aggregated together only if their value of B is 1. The aggregation in each window should take MAX(A) and SUM(C). The result of this process after applying it to the above table is the following:

| new_A | new_C |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 6 | 22 |
| 7 | 20 |
| 9 | 11 |
| 10 | 11 |
| 11 | 12 |

I want to do this via SQL only if possible.

I tried multiple window functions but didn't manage to achieve what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this by creating a pseudo sequence which assigns the same value to every island of a values in the `B` column.  Then, we can aggregate by this column to get the final result.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(B) OVER (ORDER BY A) AS lag_B
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN B = 1 AND lag_B = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                  OVER (ORDER BY A) AS seq
    FROM cte
)

SELECT MAX(A) AS new_A, SUM(C) AS new_C
FROM cte2
GROUP BY seq
ORDER BY MAX(A);
```

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for your answer. That worked. I just needed to add "rows unbounded preceding" after the order by clause of the sum aggregation.